# Joining Table On Social one with hyphens, and the other without

Tags: sql, join, db2

I am trying to perform a join on two tables. One table contains the employee info and the other contains their degree info.  The data type for the SSN in the employee table is varchar and contains hyphens.  However, the data type for the SSN in the degree table is integer and does not contain any hyphens. The SSN is what I need to use to link the two tables. How can I accomplish a join with this setup?

Comment: can you show us the schema (structure) of your database in which tables you want to join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to convert string to an integer:

```
select <whatever>
from employee e join
     degree d
     on e.ssn = cast(replace(d.ssn, '-', '') as int)
```

Do note that transformations on the key probably mean that indexes will not get used.  You should probably change the data type of one or the other to a consistent format.

Comment: Use a consistent datatype?  Sure, but he'd be better of using a surrogate, integer key, **NOT** the SSN.  @AcidBurn85 - using a SSN is just _asking_ for it to be stolen, especially in the context of a `JOIN` column.  You want that column encrypted and restricted as _much as possible_, so that people who shouldn't have read access (... like you, probably, even though I'm sure you're an upstanding gent) can't get at it.  Oh, and it's debatable if it's a _number_, even with the formatting - you may want to consider strings, for future sake.

Comment: Well what I'm doing is investigating what is needed to migrate to a new HR program. The current one is a very aging legacy program. I do agree it should be encrypted but unfortunately that's what we have to work with for now. Thanks for the reply!